# django templates : how to expand a variable into the string argument for the built-in tag `url`

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I am trying to make the following template snippet work:

```
<ul>
  {% for name,label in entries.items %}
    <li><a href="{% url name %}">{{ label }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As you can see `name` is a variable that I need to expand into string before passing it to the `url` built-in tag.

Unfortunately the aforementioned template snippet results in the following exception:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Any ideas or alternative methods on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work for Django >= 1.4 (iirc) - assuming `name` resolves to a valid url name and this url don't need args or kwargs. For Django 1.3x you have to add `{% load url from future %}` to your template for this to work. For django < 1.3 you're out of luck (well, you'll have to write a custom tag) - but you should possibly consider porting your code anyway.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. It works! Thanks! :)
(I am using django 1.3.7)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass variable to `{% url %}` templatetag. If `name` is valid urlpattern name this snippet should work.

If you need to convert `name` to a valid urlpattern name, you can do it by using custom filter, like this:

```
{% url name|my_filter %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be a bit redundant the creation of  a custom filter that just calls the django url resolver function; this is why I was hoping for a solution within the template.

Comment: @niekas: the exemple syntax you posted is for filters, not tags.